# Getting multiple street names near latitude and longitude programmatically for a mobile app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, mapping

I am writing an mobile app - where I would like to get list of streets near a latitude and longitude. I am getting one street but I like to get more as sometimes the street is not correct due to accuracy of latitude and give user an option to select the right street.

I am programming using Javascript and application I am developing in Phonegap.

The google map url
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=42.28684519999999,-83.0525493&radius=10&types=route&sensor=false&key=...

it returns only one street - St Clair but I am on California street.

Thanks
Aditya

Answer (score 6):

take a look at the google maps  [reverse geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
```

returns

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": street_address,
    "formatted_address": "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "275-291",
      "short_name": "275-291",
      "types": street_number
    }, {
      "long_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "short_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "types": route
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Brooklyn",
      "short_name": "Brooklyn",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Kings",
      "short_name": "Kings",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "NY",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "11211",
      "short_name": "11211",
      "types": postal_code
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 40.7142298,
        "lng": -73.9614669
      },
      "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.7110822,
          "lng": -73.9646145
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.7173774,
          "lng": -73.9583193
        }
      }
    }
  },

  ... Additional results[] ...
```

Comment: It still gives only one street name - I tried the below http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=42.28684519999999,-83.0525493&sensor=true